# Realm's Filter and BETWEEN keywod usage in .NET

Tags: c#, realm, subquery

```
public class Quest : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MaxRepeats { get; set; } 

    [Backlink(nameof(HistoryItem.Quest))]
    public IQueryable<HistoryItem> HistoryItems{ get; }       
}

public class HistoryItem : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTimeOffset DoneTime { get; set; }

    public Quest Quest { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to get:

1. <s>Filter in 1 day date range</s>
2. <s>Leave all quests that have MaxRepeats == 0 + Filter rest of quests that has been finished < MaxRepeats</s>
3. Leave all quests that have MaxRepeatsPerMonth == 0 + Filter rest of quests that has been finished < MaxRepeatsPerMonth **-- Issue**

my current code is:

```
private IQueryable<Quest> SearchQuery(DateTime day)
{
    var dayStart = day.AddMilliseconds(-100);
    var dayEnd = day.AddHours(24).AddMilliseconds(100);

    var monthStart = day.Date.AddDays(-day.Day +1).AddMilliseconds(-100);
        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(day.Year, day.Month);
    var monthEnd = monthStart.AddDays(daysInMonth).AddMilliseconds(200);

    return _db.Realm.All<Quest>().Where(a => a.StartDate < dayStart &&
                                             a.EndDate > dayEnd) // done 1
                              .Filter("MaxRepeats == 0 OR HistoryItems.@count <= MaxRepeats") // done 2
                              .Filter("MaxRepeatsPerMonth == 0 OR (HistoryItems.DoneTime BETWEEN {%@, %@}).@count <= MaxRepeatsPerMonth"); //an Issue
}
```

I have found solution for Swift(the filter syntax is the same for all languages)... but there is not possible to write

```
_db.Realm.All<HistoryItem>().Filter("DoneTime BETWEEN {%@, %@}", date1, date2);
```

as filter have only one input parameter in .NET

And I cannot write:

```
_db.Realm.All<HistoryItem>().Filter("DoneTime BETWEEN {"+ date1+","+ date2 + "}");
```

as in this case date will be written in another DateTime format than is needed for Filter() method.

Also I cannot use Where() method as it's have an limitations and I cannot use Count() inside of it. (I can use Count() only in reaml transactions, but its wrong to do so in my case).

So... How to use realm's Filter Between in .NET ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Even if in documentation written that syntax of realm's Filter is the same for all languages -- **this is not true**
2. `BETWEEN` keyword does not supported in .NET realization of Realm. (up to current version -- 3.3.0. Possibly will be supported in future, but not now)
3. Substitution of values into Filter predicate at .Net currently is not supported at all
4. Alternative of `BETWEEN` for .NET is:

.

```
.Filter($"HistoryItems.DoneTime >= {monthStartStr} && HistoryItems.DoneTime <= {monthEndStr}");
```

---

**So solution of my question is:**

```
.Filter($"MaxRepeatsPerMonth == 0 OR SUBQUERY(HistoryItems, $hi, $hi.DoneTime >= {monthStartStr} && $hi.DoneTime <= {monthEndStr}).@count <= MaxRepeatsPerMonth");
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can set format of date, e.g. `outputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`</s>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset_ToString_System_String_

**Edit**

Instead of `Filter` use `Where`

https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#queries

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Where(a => a.StartDate < dayStart && a.EndDate > dayEnd)
    .Where(x => x.MaxRepeats == 0 || x.HistoryItems.Count() <= x.MaxRepeats)
    .Where(x => MaxRepeatsPerMonth == 0 ||
                x.HistoryItems.Count(q => q.DoneTime >= date1 && q.DoneTime <= date2) <= MaxRepeatsPerMonth);
```

Comment: ofc I can,but 1. this is a wrong way, must be native way to paste dateTime obj into filter; 2. DateTime inside of NSPredicate looks like "566752095.510604" so this way will not work.

Comment: No, the question is related to "filter's" and "Between" usage. In my case I will not have ability to resolve my task with Where() method. I need exactly filter as I will have an additional condition that cannot be written in "Where()" because of limitations of it

Comment: You can use multiple times `Where` clause, which is very powerful. I updated my answer

Comment: I'ts impossible because of Count() cannot be used there. Count can be used in realm only in Filter method or inside of realm transaction. So only way I have is only to write Filter method. I cannot use Where() -- it's have an limitations of usege for realm.

Comment: I have resolved task. But still tanks for your help, friend